# Android - "The method add(int, Fragment)..."

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm following the tutorial here, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
I'm using Eclipse, and I've made the updates specified in the tutorial.

First, I getting the error "container cannot be resolved or is not a field". Then I put android:id="@+id/container" in my activity_display_message.xml file.

Now, I get the error "The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, DisplayMessageActivity.PlaceholderFragment)" for line 34 of  DisplayMessageActivity.java. I've put a comment just above the line.

I'm not sure what to make of this error.
Here are my files.

activity_display_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container" >

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
// Error is Here
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_message,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, let me know if any other information is required for an answer.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you import `android.app.Fragment` or  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should read this:
[Link to Android fragment docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

I think you should add in your layout xml

```
<fragment android:name="xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:id="@+id/xxxxxxx"
        android:layout_width="xxxxxxx"
        android:layout_height="xxxxxxx" />
```

and use the id of the fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inflate your fragment in it's own layout in other words creat a layout file for your fragment and in runtime that layout will be added to the container ( @+id/container).

Hope this will help